# Force cp to create subdirectories

Tags: command-line, directory, copy, cp

How do I force the `cp` command to create subdirectories?

For example, if have this file: `/home/test1/x/y/z.jpg` and this folder `/home/test2/temp/`.

```
cd /home/test1
cp -r ./x/y/z.jpg /home/test2/temp
```

gives `/home/test2/temp/z.jpg` if `/home/test2/temp/x/y` doesn't exists. I want `/home/test2/temp/x/y/z.jpg` to be created.

Comment: `-r` means recursive did you try cp -r z.jpg /home/test2/temp? if you let it start in the /test1 directory it should create the subdirectories

Comment: Why not `cp -r ./x /home/test2/temp` ?